# Trigger A GitHub Workflow When A New, Separate Repository is Created

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I have the following code written which is meant to add a new tag to a repository. This works well if included in the project I'm trying to update directly.

```
name: Check Github Tags

on: push

jobs: 
  check-git-tags:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Print Repository info
        run: |
          echo 'Commit:' $GITHUB_SHA
          echo 'Repository:' $GITHUB_REPOSITORY
          echo 'Workspace:' $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
          echo 'Ref:' $GITHUB_REF
          git tag
      - name: Push new tag
        id: push_new_tag
        uses: anothrNick/github-tag-action@1.17.2
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          CUSTOM_TAG: test2
      - name: Print New Tag Added
        run: echo 'New tag' ${{steps.push_new_tag.outputs.new_tag}} 'added to commit' $GITHUB_SHA 'in' $GITHUB_REPOSITORY.
```

My question: Can I execute this script from outside of another project / repository? I need to "listen" for any new repositories being created within the organization and then tag the repository to ensure it has the 'test2' tag. So I really only need the workflow to run on the very first push to any new repo. But I don't know who will create the repo, what it will be called, etc. Is it possible to run this as a separate script?